# Laravel - Display data on page when textbox value is fetch in database

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a page here which get all the value that has the same `employee_no`. here is my page.

here in my page, see the textbox? that is the data that im fetching and that will be my basis when I fetch all the records that has the same number.

[image]

so when i display that employee number, then all the data must be displayed. but on my case, no data is being displayed here take a look.

whereas, the final output should be this.
[image]

here is my view

```
 {!! Form::open(['action' => 'Admin\EmployeeFilemController@insertSchedule', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}

         {{Form::text('txtEmployeeNo', $employee->employee_no,['class' => 'form-control'])}}             
               {!! Form::close() !!}
```

here is my contoller

```
    public function createSchedule(Request $request, $id)
{
    $employee = Employeefm::find($id);
    $employNum =  $request->input('txtEmployeeNo');
    $employeeSched = Schedule::where(['employee_no'=>$employNum])->get();
    // dd($request->all);
    return view('admin.employeemaintenance.createSchedule',compact('employee','employeeSched'));
}
```

my route

```
Route::get('/admin/employeemaintenance/{id}/createSchedule', 'Admin\EmployeeFilemController@createSchedule');
```

P.S I have displayed the data because i change the code `$employNum`

```
$employeeSched = Schedule::where(['employee_no'=>$employNum])->get();
```

to this a fixed number `54232`

```
$employeeSched = Schedule::where(['employee_no'=>`54232'])->get();
```

and here is how i fetched it

```
                                    @foreach ($employeeSched as $setTime)
                              <tr>

                                 <td> {{Form::label('date_today', $setTime->date_today)}}</td>
                                 <td> {{Form::label('time_in',  $setTime->time_in)}}</td>
                                 <td> {{Form::label('time_out',  $setTime->time_out)}}</td>



                              </tr>
                              @endforeach
```

Comment: Your form action is calling "insertSchedule" and your controller method is "createSchedule". Is that intended?

Comment: @Kurucu yes sir, it is intended because the `insertSchedule` is the form which i insert data into database and `createSchedule` is where i open the page

Comment: @Kurucu will that make any conflict?

Comment: so what is the code for insertSchedule? What conflict do you think will happen - there is no data being changed here (it could do with refactoring, imho).