# Laravel - Display values with same value / number on the page

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a page here which get all the value that has the same `employee_no`. here is my page.

the page id defines which employee's name , lastname and number to define. so for example I hve 10 users and i need to set those 10 users with their time in and outs so i need to have a dependent data for this page. that is why I need text and its value to get all the data which that user has.

here in my page, see the textbox? that is the data that im fetching and that will be my basis when I fetch all the records that has the same number.

[image]

so when i display that employee number, then all the data must be displayed. but on my case, no data is being displayed here take a look.

whereas, the final output should be this.
[image]

here is my view

```
 {!! Form::open(['action' => 'Admin\EmployeeFilemController@insertSchedule', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}

         {{Form::text('txtEmployeeNo', $employee->employee_no,['class' => 'form-control'])}}             
               {!! Form::close() !!}
```

here is my contoller

```
    public function createSchedule(Request $request, $id)
{
    $employee = Employeefm::find($id);
    $employNum =  $request->input('txtEmployeeNo');
    $employeeSched = Schedule::where(['employee_no'=>$employNum])->get();
    // dd($request->all);
    return view('admin.employeemaintenance.createSchedule',compact('employee','employeeSched'));
}
```

my route

```
Route::get('/admin/employeemaintenance/{id}/createSchedule', 'Admin\EmployeeFilemController@createSchedule');
```

P.S I have displayed the data because i change the code `$employNum`

```
$employeeSched = Schedule::where(['employee_no'=>$employNum])->get();
```

to this a fixed number `54232`

```
$employeeSched = Schedule::where(['employee_no'=>`54232'])->get();
```

and here is how i fetched it

```
                                    @foreach ($employeeSched as $setTime)
                              <tr>

                                 <td> {{Form::label('date_today', $setTime->date_today)}}</td>
                                 <td> {{Form::label('time_in',  $setTime->time_in)}}</td>
                                 <td> {{Form::label('time_out',  $setTime->time_out)}}</td>



                              </tr>
                              @endforeach
```

Comment: I am quite confuse about `insertSchedule` and `createSchedule` what is your controller in above figure exactly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel - Display data on page when textbox value is fetch in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54299763/laravel-display-data-on-page-when-textbox-value-is-fetch-in-database)